# Selecionar apenas 1 radio button com ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular

Estou tentando renderizar alguns `radio buttons` usando `*ngFor` e só que consigo selecionar ou a **primeira** ou a **ultima** opção, nunca as opções do meio.

Tenho o seguinte `array`:

```
[
   {
     "title": "First question",
     "options": [
       {
         "title": "Title 1",
          "correct": 0
        },
        {
         "title": "Title 2",
          "correct": 0
        },
        {
         "title": "Title 3",
          "correct": 0
        },
        {
         "title": "Title 4",
          "correct": 1
        },
     ]
   }
]

<ion-card *ngFor="let question of questions">
  <ion-card-content>
    <form>
      {{ question.title }}
      <ion-list radio-group>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let option of question.options">
          <ion-label>{{ option.title }}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio [value]="option.correct"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>

      <button ion-button secondary full>Next question</button>
    </form>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

No exemplo acima, mesmo que renderize todos os `radio buttons` eu só consigo selecionar o `Title 1` ou o `Title 4`

Comment: Não é por causa do value que está igual nas 3 primeiras? Eles devem ter o value diferente.  Faça um teste colocando um value diferente para cada.

Comment: sim @AndréVicente, testei e realmente é o valor igual, mas isso seria um "erro" do framework certo? pois para que um radio seja considerado "unico" o `name` é que deveria ser comparado...

Comment: Dei uma olhada na documentação https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/ , parece que não tem a propriedade name. Não sei ao certo dizer se é um bug, teria que ir mais a fundo para descobrir, mas parece que quando usamos o ion-radio o ionic não cria um input type="radio" comum, por isso não se comporta igual. Boa sorte

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso vc vai precisar colocar o grupo de ion-radio em um radio-group:

```
 <ion-list radio-group>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
          <ion-label>{{item.cond}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio [value]="item.host" (click)="inserirCondominio(item)"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

Especifique o elemento input como radio.

```
 <input type="radio" name="unique_value_or_id" value="unique_value_or_id"/>
```